# React Native Android: View manager for tag -1 could not be found probably caused by React Native Reanimated

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am receiving the following error when running my React Native app on Android shortly after startup of the app (but the app already starts to render some component before it crashes with the error):

[image: React Native error View manager for tag -1 could not be found]

I am using React Native 0.65.1 with Hermes enabled on Android with React Native Reanimated 2.3.0-alpha.3.

Did anybody experience this error before and has a solution to the problem? Thanks a lot!

The Smart Home Maker

Answer (score 0):

For now I was able to solve it by downgrading to `React Native 0.64.2` and `React Native Reanimated 2.0.0` as a workaround.